# How to make routelink return the correct URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, routelink

here is the procedure to duplicate the issue.

1. start new mvc 4 project.
2. add the following lines to the RegisterRoutes() method just before the "Default" route

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Test",
           url: "Test/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
   );
   ```
3. add the following to Index.cshtml and About.cshtml

   ```
   @Html.RouteLink("link to TestController", "Test")
   ```

As you can see that the generated html code is different for the 2 pages. I would expect the URL is "/Test" which is rendered correctly for Index.cshtml, but it become "/Test/About" for About.cshtml.

My question is if there is any documented way to generate the same correct URL. The above example is created just for demonstration purpose. I would like to use the routing table information to generate menu.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the engine is setting the `action` route value from the current page ("Index", "About").  So one way to fix this is to "unset" that route value:

```
@Html.RouteLink("link to Test Controller", "Test", new { action = String.Empty })
```

Comment: I have found that I had to specify `controller = String.Empty` as well in order to get it to render the default Url as defined in the RouteConfig.

Answer (score 2):

Register your route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TestUrl",
                url: "Test",
                defaults: new { controller = "TestController", action = "TestAction" }
            );
```

add the following to TestAction.cshtml

```
 @Html.RouteLink("Test", "TestUrl")
```

Now your URL is /Test, hoping this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way would be to just specify a blank action.

```
@Html.RouteLink("link to TestController", "", "Test")
```

This will produce `/Test`

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrive here looking for **.netcore razor page RouteLink** syntax, don't use RouteLink's "**page**" reserved member. It will not work for the routeValues object as some have suggested. Instead, use the following format:

```
<a asp-page="RazorPage">RazorPage</a>
```

*This handles trailing and the absence of trailing forward slashes.* The RazorPage is the name of the page without any characters after the first ".".