# Can't create @Html.Routelink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I created aHomeController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Experiment1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

with a View for the Index action method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>My Photo Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   @Html.RouteLink("Go","Menu")
</body>
</html>
```

and a MenuController with a View:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Experiment1.Controllers
{
    public class MenuController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>SomeText</h2>
```

Here is the code for RouteConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Experiment1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Menu",
             url: "{controller}/{action}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Menu", action = "Index"}
         );
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use `@Html.RouteLink("Go","Menu")` in the HomeController View, it goes to HomeController instead of MenuController.

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make routelink return the correct URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521664/how-to-make-routelink-return-the-correct-url)

Comment: Yes i saw this,but it didn't help me.

Comment: Your view is generated by the `HomeController` so its passing `Home` as the controller. Change the definition of the `Menu` route to `url: "Menu/{action}",`

Comment: It works thank you.